# Is this the correct way to overwrite a css background image with a solid color?

Tags: css

I have a default css sheet that uses an image for the background but for the mobile version of the site I want to overwrite the image with a solid color.

My default style sheet looks like this:

```
background-image: url('../img/gray_hash.png');
```

My current CSS file looks like this:

```
background-image: url('');  
background-color: #ffffff; !important;
```

Is this the correct way to do it?  If I simply add a background color the image seems to take priority.

Comment: `background-color` is under the `background-image`, one doesn't really affect the other per se.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. To remove a background image, use `background-image:none`

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the shorthand

```
background: url('../img/gray_hash.png'); // (with any other properties needed)
```

and overwrite with

```
background: white;
```